# Cisco IOS Show | Filter | redirect

Tags: cisco, ios

I am new to Cisco IOS and I have one question that I have come across. Please reference this thread. [Reference](https://serverfault.com/questions/430702/cisco-command-output-redirect-to-a-local-file) The answer to that thread states that in Cisco IOS you can run a command, filter it down to what you want, and then redirect the output somewhere. For example, `show run | i username | redirect flash0:/output.txt`. The answer goes into more depth that you could do `show run | i username | redirect tftp://IPaddress/myfile.txt` with a TFTP server setup.

**I can do**
 Note - in order for this to be successful, I have to be in "enable" mode on the router

`show ip interface brief | redirect tftp://IPaddress/output.txt`

**I can't do**
 Note - (also in "enable" mode)

`show ip interface brief | i LoopBack0 | redirect tftp://IPaddress/output.txt`

How can I filter down my show command and then redirect the output as stated in the thread?

**Update** I just realized I messed up and didnt read closely that not all devices support multiple pipes. How can I determine which ones do and how can I work around this problem?

Comment: As an aside: Please see [What information should I include or obfuscate in my posts?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) Obfuscating an RFC1918 address serves no purpose but confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to write some sort of tool that works across everything, go lowest common denominator: If you have some devices/ios versions in your environment that don't support multiple pipes, then don't use them at all.

You'll just need to filter your data when you're processing it after it's been exported from the device, instead.